# iText pagesize landscape - broswer doesn't render landscape

Tags: itext

I want to create pdf page in landscape mode but the browser seems to render the generated page in portrait mode always.. same issue with both IE and Firefox.. here is what I did to get Landscape mode..

```
 Rectangle a4 = PageSize.A4;
 Rectangle a4LandScape = a4.rotate();
 doc.setPageSize(a4LandScape);
```

I can see that width>height after line 3, but once the page is rendered to browser, I get portrait again.. Is there any other way to do this?

PS: I am using old version of iText(2.7), there is no option such as Legal_LandScape for PageSize

Comment: wouldn't be better to write a one line `doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a *very* old version of iText so I can't say for certain what your problem is. I can tell you that in recent versions (4.x and 5.x) that `setPageSize` only affects new pages added and has no effect on existing pages. Usually when you create your `Document` object you set the intended page size there. If you need to add a different size page you call `setPageSize` directly before calling `NewPage()`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply Chris.. yes I am using old version of iText because I am restricted by Spring MVC to do so.. it seems like even newest version of Spring MVC (3.1) doesn't integrate latest iText.. There is a clash with PdfWriter class if I use latest version of itext..

Comment: but this problem is solved though.. I forgot to call newPage() after setting the page size.. I have corrected that.. now I have another issue with footer/header.. can you help me with this? Thanks in advance! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234124/itext-document-footer-on-eachpage-spring-mvc